# SPFX design using office-ui-fabric

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, office-ui-fabric

I am new to spfx and I have been trying to get the office-ui-fabric design for my elements in the spfx application.
So I have started with the design of a button. I have done the following steps to get button design of ui-fabric.

- Installed -- `npm install @microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core --save-dev`
- Imported `import { Button } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';` in webpart file.
- In render method I have a button

  `<button class="{styles.button}">`

But it does not apply any design to button. Am I missing anything here

Comment: this might help: https://n8d.at/blog/npm-package-for-office-ui-fabric-colours-released-ok-a-while-back/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test sample for your reference.

```
import {
  Dropdown,
  Button
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib'
...
<Button >
              ReactButton
              </Button>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can we use office-ui-fabric-react in no javascript framework app

Comment: It's based on React so I think you'd better use React as framework.https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react